# how many rra in a rrd?

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I have some rrd files. I have found a cgi script that draws a graph for this rdd. You can choose (from the webpage where the graph is drawn) if see the graph for the last hour, day, week or year.
I know that there could be more rra in a single rrd. I was thinking that for this rrd there are 4 rra, one for the last hour, one for the last week etc)

Do you know how can I verify this? is there any command?

Answer (score 3):

note that the charts are not immediately tied to the available rras ... you can choose any resolution you want ... depending on the rras available the steps in the chart will be wider or smaller.

Comment: got it, it makes sense. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Check out '[rrdtool info](http://www.mrtg.org/rrdtool/doc/rrdinfo.en.html)' and see if that gets you what you need.

Comment: I used rrdtool dump  and I got the information, thx anyway :)